# Pentaho maven/gradle dependencies

Tags: java, maven, gradle, pentaho

I searched on many repository hubs but could not find the latest pentaho report engine repositories  for `maven or gradle`. I need only report engine libs and its dependencies.

Please share if you know some repos i can add in my gradle's buildconfig or maven's pom.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the GAVC that you are looking for?

Comment: @JBaruch i guess something like G-penthao A-core V-latest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the repository you are looking for can be found here:

http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo

Comment: Provided link is broken

Answer (score 3):

For classes from packages like org.pentaho.platform.web.http for version 5

```
<repository>
        <id>pentaho-releases</id>
        <url>http://repository.pentaho.org/artifactory/repo/</url>
    </repository>
```

And

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>pentaho</groupId>
            <artifactId>pentaho-platform-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

URL for Pentaho artifacts repository: 
http://repo.pentaho.org/artifactory/pentaho/